# prevent cell edits in ipython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I would like to run a [public ipython notebook server](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.1.0/interactive/public_server.html#notebook-public-server) to serve up a notebook which has non-editable code cells which can be run by the user.

Why, you ask? Because I don't want arbitrary python run on my server, but I do want users to be able to interface with the python scripts via raw_input(). (this means I can't use a static html nbview or reveal.js slideshow).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know only  IPython 1.0 supports raw_input() . and its very obvious because Ipython is like interactive command shell , you give commands and it replies. and for greater flexibility in Ipython notebook it can be divided even into totally irrelevant cells which can run separately.So it cant respond according to inputs its just command-reply mechanism .

Comment: I was surprised to find that my scripts which use raw_input() work just fine in the IPython notebook. Like you say, it is like a web-interface to the interactive shell. What do you mean it is just a "command-reply mechanism"?